# Communication between Arduino and Raspberry Pi over USB

Tags: usb, arduino, communication

I have an Arduino connected over USB with a Raspberry Pi. A Python program is sending a value over USB, then the arduino receives it and turns the LED on. The Arduino is sending a analogue value from A0 to the Python program on the Raspberry. But Python receives sometimes `024`, `24` or `4` instead of `1024`. How can I fix this? Here is my code:
http://www.bitsharr.com/Hsoxw7nG

Arduino Code:

```
int led = 13;
char  charIn;

int sensorPin = A0;    // select the input pin for the potentiometer
int sensorValue = 0;  // variable to store the value coming from the sensor
long previousMillis = 0; 
long interval = 1000;  
// the setup routine runs once when you press reset:

void setup() {           
  // initialize the digital pin as an output.
  pinMode(led, OUTPUT);  
  Serial.begin(9600); //This initializes the USB as a serial port
}

void loop() {
  if (Serial.available()) {
    delay(5); // warten bis alle Daten da sind
    while(Serial.available() > 0) {
    charIn =(char) Serial.read();
    if (charIn == '1') {
      digitalWrite(led,HIGH);
      delay(5000);
      digitalWrite(led,LOW);
    }
  }
}
```

Python Code:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

from serial import Serial

ser = Serial('/dev/ttyUSB0', 9600)
x=ser.readline()
ser.write('1')
print(x)
def cleanup( str ):
  result = ""

  for c in str:
    if( (c >= "0") and (c <= "9") ):
       result += c

  return result

print( cleanup(x))
#ser.write("1") 
sensorValue = analogRead(sensorPin); //Reads the voltage of the resistor.
Serial.println(sensorValue); //Writes the voltage on the Serial port.
}
```

Answer (score 1):

### For starters, you are using Arduino code in your Python code.

```
sensorValue = analogRead(sensorPin); //Reads the voltage of the resistor.
Serial.println(sensorValue); //Writes the voltage on the Serial port.
```

**How would your computer know what values are on your Arduino?** You need to move this into the Arduino code. I can't tell you where: you never specified exactly what you want to accomplish with this code.

---

Some more problems with your code:

- `#ser.write("1")` should be `ser.write("1")`
- These two lines aren't bad but they're a bad coding practice to include because you don't use them:
  `long previousMillis = 0;`

  `long interval = 1000;`

---

> But python receives sometimes 024, 24 or 4 instead of 1024.

The Arduino never *sent* anything; there is no `serial.print();` or `serial.println();`! I don't know how you are receiving data. If you make the edits to your code above and/or specify *exactly* what you want to do (i.e. *Send a 1 to the Arduino, turn a LED on, get sensor data back every five seconds, if the data is above 50%, turn the light off*) and still don't know what to do, feel free to comment for clarification.